# Movement of a biological cell in water-Probability of collision?

Tags: thermodynamics, fluid-statics, diffusion, brownian-motion

Firstly, I apologize, as I am a systems biology scientist, so quite naïve when it comes to physics and mathematics. There is a chance that my question is deemed as very simple, but help would be greatly appreciated.

I am trying to write an ODE (or PDE, depending on the needs)-based model that can explain cell migration into different tissues. An important part is capturing the behavior seen in simple *in vitro* systems, to then extrapolate it to a more complex scenario (what may actually happen in a human being).

As a starting point, it would be good if I could somehow have  calculate the speed at which a particle (a cell) randomly moves in the culture medium. My idea is then to use this to calculate a certain "probability of interaction" of this cell with neighbor cells during a given timespan.

So far, I tried to implement something similar to Fick's law of diffusion. Problems are:
a) There is no gradient in the in vitro system, as everything is mixed and well stirred. Movement occurs (I believe?) because of convective currents in the media + the agitation of the incubator, but it's a random movement, not directed to a specific location
b) Cells are big. In the order of 6-15 micrometers of diameter, and as such will not really follow ideal gas assumptions or other simplistic assumptions Brownian motion is based upon

I know the volume of the aqueous medium, the surface of the container (and as such, the volume/surface ratio, which is interesting for defining interactions), the count of the different cell types (so we can define something similar to a "density") and their mean volumes (which, upon some assumptions, can give us some idea of how light or heavy they are compared to the aqueous environment they are in). I apologize for all the incorrect terminology I may have already used.

So far, I tried to calculate the collision frequency using the following formula:
$$
Z=N_{1}\cdot N_{2}\cdot \pi (r_{1} + r_{2})^{2}\cdot\sqrt{\frac{8K_{B}\cdot T}{\pi \cdot \mu _{1, 2}}} 
$$

Where $Z$ is the average number of collisions expected per time unit in the given volume, $N_{1}$ is the number of molecules (cells, in my case) of one certain class, termed $1$, $N_{2}$ the number of molecules (cells) of a different class ($2$), $r_{1}, r_{2}$ are the radius of each cell type, $K_{B}$ is Boltzman's constant and $\mu _{1, 2} = \frac{m_{1}\cdot m_{2}}{(m_{1}+m_{2})}$ is the effective mass, calculated as indicated.

When using it, I obtain a very low value, and I guess it is because the assumptions used to derive these formula do not hold in my case. It could also be that I am totally off. Any ideas on how to solve the problem?

Comment: If the only cellular movement occurs due to convective currents, you need to understand those currents in order to estimate collisions. For example, if you have very smooth laminar flow, it seems to me that there would be very few collisions, since all the cells would be moving within primarily non-interacting streams.